# How do we access a contract that was deployed by another contract in Truffle?

Tags: truffle

I am trying to figure out how do we access Contract2's instance in Truffle's test if it was deployed by Contract1 in Truffle Develop? Can't seem to find a question that described my issue exactly so sorry in advance if there is one already!

I have a BallotFactory contract that generates a new Ballot contract as below.

```
contract BallotFactory {
address[] public deployedBallotsAddress;

function createBallot(
    string memory _title,
    string memory _description,
    string memory _option1,
    string memory _option2
) public {
    address newBallotAddress = address(
        new Ballot(_title, _description, _option1, _option2, msg.sender)
    ); 
    deployedBallotsAddress.push(newBallotAddress);
}

function getDeployedBallots() public view returns (address[] memory) {
    return deployedBallotsAddress;
}
```

I migrated the BallotFactory contract.

```
const BallotFactory = artifacts.require("BallotFactory");
module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(BallotFactory);
};
```

In my Truffle test's beforeEach:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
factoryInstance = await BallotFactory.new({ from: accounts[0] });

await factoryInstance.createBallot(
  "President",
  "Vote for Alice or Bob",
  "Alice",
  "Bob",
  {
    from: accounts[0],
  }
);

[ballotAddress] = await factoryInstance.getDeployedBallots();

console.log(ballotAddress);

ballotInstance = await Ballot.deployed(ballotAddress); });
```

console.log(ballotAddress) returns as address which I guess means that BallotFactory successfully deployed a new Ballot contract. But when I try to access the deployed ballot instance in the last line, I get the error: "Ballot has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)". There are functions like voting on the Ballot contract that needs testing later in the 'it' hence the need to access it.

Testing is done on Truffle Develop without ganache.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have this:

```
const Ballot = artifacts.require("Ballot");
```

Change this:

```
ballotInstance = await Ballot.deployed(ballotAddress);
```

To this:

```
ballotInstance = Ballot.at(ballotAddress);
```

Comment: Oh that did it, thank you so much! 

Sorry goodvibration, do you mind if I ask if which documentation I should refer to find functions and methods like this one? Is it web3js or truffle specific? I tried looking through the docs but couldn't find .at().

Comment: @SeanSing: Huh, very good question. Within a Truffle test, you have a global object named `web3`, which depends on the Web3 version that your Truffle version relies on. For example, Truffle 4.x relies on Web3 0.x, while Truffle 5.x relies on Web3 1.x. On top of that, as you've noted, some of these functions are not even part of Web3 documentation, because they are some sort of wrappers of web3 functions, which are implemented by Truffle. For example, the global object named `artifacts`. Specifically for your question about the `at` function, see my next comment below...

Comment: @SeanSing: As far as I understand, Truffle's `artifacts.require` is a wrapper around `web3.eth.contract` (on web3 0.x) and around `web3.eth.Contract` (on web3 1.x). It returns an object which describes your contract. On this object, you can call `new(arg1, arg2, arg3)`, thus deploying a new instance of your contract, or you can use `at(address)` in order to get a "pointer" to an already deployed contract. On the web3 layer, the `at` function exists only on version 0.x as far as I know (see [the official documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract)).

Comment: @SeanSing: On Truffle 5.x, which uses web3 1.x, I am not sure whether or not the `at` function is still viable. If it is, then it obviously doesn't rely on web3's `at` function, since it is no longer available in that version of web3.

Comment: To conclude this, here are the links that I always use: [Web3 v0.x](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3js-api-reference), [Web3 v1.x](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/), [Truffle](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts).

Comment: That's a really good set of documentation to look into! Didn't think of checking the Javascript API docs specifically. Really appreciate the time you took to explain the background and provide the links. Will be a go-to for me from now on as well!

Comment: And I just had a check, I managed to run this with Truffle 5.x, so your hunch that it doesn't rely on web3's `at` function is true hence my curiosity if it was documented in Truffle instead.

Comment: @seansing: I don't recall seeing it on Truffle documentation, but I know for a fact that it is not available on Web3 v1.x, which is what Truffle 5.x relies on. So if you're able to use it on Truffle 5.x, then it definitely means that Truffle implements wrappers around at least some of the Web3 functions. Another example of it is that you don't need to do `myContract.methods.func(...).call(...)`, but you can simply do `myContract.func(...)`. This is for sure a "truffle shortcut".

Comment: And hey, [here is Truffle's documentation on the `at` function](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts#use-a-contract-at-a-specific-address). Note that the use of `await` in their example is a mistake in the docs (it won't harm the execution of your code, but it is not needed, since function `at` is not `async`).

Comment: Right, will keep the versioning in mind from now! Yes, I managed to follow the truffle shortcut on functions calling. 
Haha, you found it! So embarrassed that I missed it. I combed through and through before deciding to make this post. You're right, but I think in this example `await` was used as they needed to deploy a MetaCoin instance before using it with `at`? Kind of like my example I guess, I tried running my test without `await` before the `at` function and got a failing test with `undefined`. But yes, if the instance already existed then `await` wouldn't be required.

Comment: @seansing: No, you're wrong. Function `at` is not used in order to deploy a new contract. It is used in order to get a logical object which represents an already deployed contract. So there is no RPC or transaction involved here (i.e., no `call` or `send` which interacts with the ethereum node that you're connected to). Therefore, there is no need to use `await` when calling this function.

Comment: If the contract isn't already deployed at the specified address ("already exist" as you referred to it in your comment), then you will not be able to use the logical object returned by `at` in order to interact with that contract (because obviously the contract "isn't there"). I don't quite see how the solution that I gave you (`ballotInstance = Ballot.at(ballotAddress)`) can possibly work for you with `await` but not without it.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I understand that the `at` is not used to deploy a contract, that's done by `new` or `deployed`. So what I said was that in the docs, maybe they had `await` prior to the `at` because it needed to wait for a MetaCoin contract to be deployed first (possibly in previous lines of code) so that it can use the `at` function on the deployed contract. Was trying to justify why they might have the `await` in the docs.

Comment: As for my example, the reason it didn't work without `await` is because it needed the BallotFactory to deploy a Factory contract first before I can interact with the deployed Factory contract using `at`. I believe we both have the same understanding though! Just some misunderstanding in the comments.

Comment: @seansing: AFAIK, you don't just add `await` in your code to make sure that some previous `async` function call completes. You use `await` either directly on the function call, or on the promise object that has returned. Hence, being that function `at` is not `async`, using `await at(...)` is pointless.

Comment: Hmm, you made a good point as well. I'll go through my code again and see if anything else is causing it fail without `await`. Will update here if I find anything! Thanks again man, appreciate the discussions.